# ¿Es posible tener una entidad fuerte que abarque varias entidades en modelado de base de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, oracle

me ronda una duda referente al modelado de base de datos les comento el caso: Tengo una base de datos con alguna de las tablas que son

```
PERSONA (nro_documento,apellidos,nombres,fnacimiento,id_genero,id_tdocumento)
TRABAJADOR (nro_documento,codtrabajador,sueldo,id_departamento)
FORMACION (nro_documento,institucion,descripcion,id_tformacion,id_eformacion)
CONTRATO (nro_documento,id_contrato,inicio,fin,cese,remuneracion,id_tcontrato,id_econtrato)
ENTRADA_SALIDA (nro_documento,id_es,fecha,hora,id_tes,id_ees)
```

Además de

```
GENERO (id, codigo, etiqueta, descripcion, situacion)
TIPO_DOCUMENTO
ESTADO_CIVIL 
TIPO_TRABAJADOR
ESTADO_TRABAJADOR
TIPO_FORMACION
ESTADO_FORMACION
TIPO_CONTRATO
ESTADO_CONTRADO
TIPO_E_S
ESTADO_E_S
```

(todas estas ultimas con mismos atributos).

Cardinalidad principal:

```
persona (1 a 1) trabajador
trabajador (1 a n) formacion
trabajador (1 a n) contrato
trabajador (1 a n) entrada_salida
```

Lo mencionado es el estado actual del modelado,lo que yo quiero hacer es las tablas (genero,tipo_documento,estado_civil, tipo_trabajador, estado_trabajador,tipo_formacion,estado_formacion, tipo_contrato, estado_contrado, estado_e_s y tipo_e_s) quitarlas y representarlas por 2 las cuales son tipo_entidad y entidad, donde:

```
//representa las diferentes tablas que quitare
TIPO_ENTIDAD (cod_te,etiqueta,situacion) 
//son las opciones que tienen cada una
ENTIDAD (id,codigo,etiqueta,descripcion,situacion,cod_te)
```

Cardinalidad :

```
TIPO_ENTIDAD (1 a n) ENTIDAD
```

**ANTES:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**DESPUES:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es recomendable hacer lo que menciono o no?, lo digo porque si en alguno momento creo una tabla equipo_informatico esta tendra un tipo y estado que con la situacion actual crearia dos tablas en la base mientras con la situacion que pienso solo un par de registros en la tabla tipo_entidad.

Comment: Tu pregunta es bastante interesante y me gustaría ayudar pero podrías organizarla mejor? Colocar la información de tablas en formato de código

Comment: habria que ver la informacion que estas guardando, ver si no hay duplicidad y si la hay normalizar las tablas para evitarlo

Comment: No hay duplicidad, mi duda va enfocada al hecho sencillo que tengo tablas que no dependen de otras como son GENERO(masculino,femenino), TIPO_DOCUMENTO(dni,carnet extrangeria) entre otras, y las manejo en mi base de datos como tablas. Ahora se me ocurrió mejor reemplazar por dos tablas, en una ira las posibles tablas que necesite crear y en la otra las opciones para la tabla creada. Ahora no se si seria una buena manera de trabajar o debería dejarlo tal cual?  y seguir creando tablas si es necesario pero que posiblemente solo contendrán 2 registros como genero.

Comment: Como poder se puede, pero deberías entonces controlar que por ejemplo un trabajador no sea hombre y mujer al mismo tiempo, y eso debería hacerse a nivel aplicación por que el modelo lo permitiría eventualmente. No sé que es lo que buscas, pero no le veo demasiadas ventajas a este modelo, en el contexto que planteas.

Comment: Lo que quería era evitar crear tablas por cada tipo o estado de tabla (que contendrán en algunos casos solo 2 registros como el caso de genero), y reemplazarlas por dos. Ademas cabe mencionar que mis tablas tipos, estados y demás tablas mencionadas contienen los mismos atributos.

Comment: ESto esta basado en opiniones.. pero... vas a tener un problema grave... tus querys van a ser ultracomplejos innecesariamente..piensa, como vas a mostrar los datos de las personas, si la tabla persona se tiene que joinear varias veces con la tabla de tipo_entidad, para traer el genero, el tipo de documento, y probablemente mas cosas...

Comment: Ya veo, entonces se podría decir que se puede hacer pero no es recomendable.

Comment: como podes hacer, podes hacer lo que quieras.. prohibido no hay nada... pero no se hace asi, y no vas a encontrar casi base de datos asi (salvo detalles muy particulares, por ejemplo en wordpress), por cosas como las que te detalle..